# Need help with RRT star algorithm for robotic arm

Tags: ros, rrt, ompl-planning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
I'm new at ROS and was hoping to make a robotic arm with 5 DoF plan paths with this algorithm (RRT star with Ball Tree). I have found references to it in the OMPL package, but I still don't know how to use it.
I'll appreciate any guidance in this matter!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29154/need-help-with-rrt-star-algorithm-for-robotic-arm/) by [Carlos](https://answers.ros.org/users/1919/carlos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2012-03-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Refer to this [link](http://ompl.kavrakilab.org/core/genericPlanning.html). There you 'll find some guidelines regarding setting state space/bounds, using existing planners in ompl, setting start/goal states and find solution.

These are the following steps basically(for example SE2):-

//1. construct the instance of state space we are planning in->for mobile base SE2

```
ompl::base::StateSpacePtr space(new ompl::base::SE2StateSpace());
```

//2. get bounds from worldmap and set it to bounds for the planner

```
ompl::base::RealVectorBounds bounds(2);
space->as<ompl::base::SE2StateSpace>()->setBounds(bounds);
```

//3. Create an instance of ompl::geometric::SimpleSetup

```
ompl::geometric::SimpleSetup simple_setup(space);
```

//4. Set state validity checker

```
simple_setup.setStateValidityChecker(boost::bind(&Function_Name, this, _1));
```

//7. set start and goal state to planner

```
simple_setup.setStartAndGoalStates(ompl_scoped_state_start, ompl_scoped_state_goal);
```

//8 Set Planner type

```
ompl::base::SpaceInformationPtr si_ptr = simple_setup.getSpaceInformation();
ompl::base::PlannerPtr target_planner_ptr(new ompl::geometric::EST(si_ptr));
simple_setup.setPlanner(target_planner_ptr);
```

//9. Solve

```
simple_setup.solve(1.0);
```

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [VN](https://answers.ros.org/users/841/vn/) with karma: 373 on 2012-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Carlos](https://answers.ros.org/users/1919/carlos/) on 2012-03-21**:
Thanks a lot! but I really ment I'm new at ROS, I have just followed the ROS Tutorials and created an URDF for my robot, so I don't quite get how does it all fit with the code you propose. Sorry for the ignorance and thanks again for the help :)